# iMessage Photo Browser hide navigation bar on tap effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, imessage

I am trying to create an copy of the "photo browser" that exists in iMessage when you tap on a photo in a chat thread. I am stuck on how they get the behaviour of the navigation bar to disappear properly on tap.

Currently I call

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

When the view is tapped to hide the navigation bar. However this causes the views to move upward awkwardly because of how views respond to the top layout guide. iMessage has it so the views completely ignore the top layout guide and just sit right underneath it. How can i get this same behaviour?

Here is my code to create the collection view of photos:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_collectionView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

.........

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width  - collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.left - collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.right, collectionView.bounds.size.height - collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.bottom - collectionViewLayout.sectionInset.top);
}
```